# I have two threads how do I know if they are running concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to create two threads that run concurrently how can I test if they are running concurrently it seams in the output that the threads are running after the current thread ends? IS this happening or are thy running concurrently?

```
public class Start {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ThreadOne();
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread(); // Static Method
    t.setName("Thread One");
    System.out.println(t);

        for(int i = 0; i<=100; i++) {
            System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
        }

    }

}

public class ThreadOne implements Runnable {
Thread t;
public ThreadOne() {
    t =new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
    System.out.println("Child Thread" + t);
    t.start();
}
@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i<=100; i++) {

            System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);

    }

}

}
```

Output

```
Main Thread: 0
Main Thread: 1
Main Thread: 2
Main Thread: 3
Main Thread: 4
Main Thread: 5
Main Thread: 6
Main Thread: 7
Main Thread: 8
Main Thread: 9
Main Thread: 10

Child Thread: 0
Child Thread: 1
Child Thread: 2
Child Thread: 3
Child Thread: 4
Child Thread: 5
Child Thread: 6
Child Thread: 7
Child Thread: 8
Child Thread: 9
Child Thread: 10
```

Comment: Starting a thread takes time.  You can do a lot of work in one thread because a second end starts.  BTW This means it doesn't always makes sense to pass work to a another thread if the work to create the thread exceeds the benefit of that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it looks like the main thread finishes before the child thread starts.  And there is nothing in the code that you have written that would *require* either simultaneous or interleaved execution of the two threads.

---

Your broader question is interesting.

> I'm trying to create two threads that run concurrently how can I test if they are running concurrently

I actually don't think that it is possible to *definitively* test if or prove that two threads in an application actually run simultaneously.  As far as I am aware, any externally observable pattern of execution that could be produced by threads executing (literally) simultaneously, could also in theory be produced by threads that are time-slicing ... on a system with a single core.

In practice, the granularity of time-slicing is such that you *can typically* see a difference in the behaviour.  But I think that you need to assess the available evidence on a case-by-case basis ... in conjunction with the code of the specific application.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like it because the output of the first thread is so fast that the secound hasn't started. if you do 10000 iterations in your for-loop, or add an `Thread.sleep(1000);` to the first for loop, you see that they are run concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the bin of the java folder there is an application [`jvisualvm.exe`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html) ( in case of Windows platform). Execute that, you will be able to monitor threads.

Answer (score 0):

They are running concurrently. I have tried the code and sure it is. I think you should see more output. The output you show us is just printing ten times. It can not tell truth. You can change 100 to 1000 and then you will find the truth.